# Clear value on textareas and inputs using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put a script where you can clear the value on inputs and text-area by clicking on a button. I copied a script on the web that can clear my inputs it worked but how can I include textareas on it?

Here's the script:

```
$("#btnpost").click(function(){
var inp = $("input");
if(inp.val()) {
   inp.val(''); 
}
}); 

<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Insert Title Here">
<textarea class="form-control " rows="5" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea> 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  id="btnpost">
```

Post

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnpost").click(function(){
   $('input ,textarea').each(function(){
   if($(this).val() !=""){
    $(this).val() = "";
  }
});
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do like this. assign id `id="textArea"` to `textarea`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btnpost").click(function(){
  $("#inputEmail3").val("");
  $("#textArea").val("");
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Insert Title Here">
<textarea id="textArea" class="form-control " rows="5" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnpost">ClearMe</button>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lfw43kc/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If those elements are inside a form I'd recommend to use [.reset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

```
$("#btnpost").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('form').reset();
});
```

Just a preference, it seems 'cleaner' to me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be this one:

```
$("#btnpost").click(function(){
   $("#inputEmail3, #textArea").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use html reset button. You only need to wrap all your elements inside a form element.

```
<form>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Insert Title Here">
<textarea class="form-control " rows="5" placeholder="Insert Content Here"></textarea> 
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/d37qpghz/)